# I want to use only Google SQL only, without Storage. Can I?

Tags: sql, google-app-engine

I have a shared hosting. I want to use Google SQL, but keep files on my hosting, don't want to use Google Storage. Can I do that?

I granted access to my Google SQL DB for my Shared Server IP. But I still cannot connect. Got an error smth about permission.

I'm using Drupal 7.

Pls, tell me, is it madatory to use Google Storage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809306/connecting-php-code-on-compute-engine-to-cloud-sql-securely

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make sure you know the definitions about both Google Cloud SQL and Google Cloud Storage first, these are two different products and services.

'Google Cloud SQL is a MySQL database that lives in Google's cloud.It has all the capabilities and functionality of MySQL, with a few additional features and a few unsupported features '
according to: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/introduction

'Google Cloud Storage is an Internet service to store data in Google's cloud. It provides a simple programming interface which enables developers to take advantage of Google's own reliable and fast networking infrastructure to perform data operations in a secure and cost effective manner.' according to: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/overview

FAQ about Cloud SQL: https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq